Apple's Photos app creates on macOS green bands when exporting (iPhone)HEIC images to JPEG/TIFF files
Apple's Photos app creates on macOS green bands when exporting (iPhone)HEIC images to JPEG/TIFF files
When I export HEIC pictures on my Intel Macbook (running macOS Monterey) to JEPG or TIFF files, I get strange green bands in the lower half of the image. I attach a sample export at the bottom of this post.
This does not happen when I export the same pictures (synced via Apple's photo sync) on an Apple Silicon Mac Mini (running macOS Sonoma).
What can I do about this? Is this a Monterey thing? Or a Intel Mac thing? Can I use another tool to export images as TIFF from the Photos app?
Maybe others had the same issue and know how to resolve it.


I just tried on my 2014 Intel Mac with Monterey 12.7.5 and I don't get any green bands.  I exported a HEIC from my iPhone X (iOS 16.7.8) to both TIFF and JPEG and didn't see an issue.  Do you also get the bands if you do a "Save As"?

Looks like a broken Jpeg file to me. Is there enough space on the disk? Did you run disk health diagnostics recently? Are the red things part of the original picture?

I think, there might be an issue with the graphics solution on your mac. Either hardware or software.  As the drivers are part of the OS, there is not much you can do.

@PeterM I use File -> Export -> Export 1Photo. In my Photos.app  I cannot find a Save As menu entry.

@xenoid The original is a HEIC picture. The export is a TIFF or a JPEG. The green and the red artifacts are only in the exports. As said on my other Mac I can export perfectly.

@KaiMattern Mmmmh, nothing I can do? I guess it is a software issue. Maybe reinstalling the Photos app helps. (Not that i know how to do this...) I hope others had teh same issue and know how to resolve it...

@halloleo I just realized we are exporting from different Apps.  I opened my HEIC image in Preview and exported from there.  I didn't do it from Photos.  We should both try each other's methods and see what happens.
